# "les toilettes pour femmes" ou "les toilettes aux femmes"

Tags: choix-de-mot

Les deux phrases sont-elles correctes ?

Y a-t-il une difference entre elles ?

J'ai essayé de chercher avec Google, et aussi de dialoguer avec chatGPT, mais je ne suis pas sûre.

(also, finding any grammar mistakes in the question itself would be lovely)

Answer (score 2):

"Toilettes **pour** femmes" est la forme correcte.
Il est aussi possible d'utiliser: "Toilettes **des** femmes".

Comment: Aussi *Toilettes femmes* / *Toilettes dames*.

Answer (score 1):

"Toilettes **aux** femmes" n'est pas correct. No grammar mistakes in your question at all! Good job!

Comment: Bienrevenu! (Si je peux inventer un mot)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Revenu :-) oui! Je reviens hahaha...